# Django, Webpack and Heroku: Error reading /app/webpack-stats.json

Tags: python, django, heroku, webpack, django-webpack-loader

I'm trying to use Django with Webpack on Heroku via [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/django-webpack/django-webpack-loader). After pushing the files from the repository to Heroku, I run webpack to generate the static files in `/dist` as well as `webpack-stats.json`:

```
npx webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

This works fine: both the `/dist` files and the `webpack-stats.json` file are correctly created (both are placed within `/app/`). However, when I try to load the page I get an error:

```
OSError at /
Error reading /app/webpack-stats.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?
```

The error doensn't say much other than the file `/app/webpack-stats.json` is missing; however, the file exists, its content is well-formatted and it's in the right location.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I did but I don't quite remember how.